# Android service get data by request

Tags: java, android, service, android-mediaplayer

I'm doing some mp3 player, and I need to playback music forever, until it's stops.
So, I need services
And when user closes app, service plays music, all good, but when he opens app again, I need get some information (about current song and current position) from service. With BroadcastReseiver, I think.
And do it without stopping service.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries for mp3 players have a function to help you get the location where the music is at. What library are you using for playing your mp3's?